# How do I add a new line before appending(+=) my variable with another variable in python?

Tags: python, rasa, rasa-x

I am using Rasa X as my front end. I can't see how that would have anything to do with it, but I figured I will mention it just in case. Anyway, I have a variable that is collecting cell values from my excel sheet. I am using a loop statement add the values to my variable "requested_information". After the loop finishes, I add the string "\n" and my variable "missing_info" to it. When requested_information is printed, the new line is not in there. Here is the text result:

[image]

And here is my code:

```
for column in load_data.column_names:
        project_name_cell = str(sheet["B{}".format(row)].value)
        main_cell = str(sheet["" + column + "{}".format(row)].value)
        if project_id_provided == False:
            requested_information += "The " + load_data.column_names[column] + " for project " + project_name_cell + " is " + main_cell + ".\n"
        else:
            if main_cell == "n/a" or main_cell == None:
                missing_info_list.append(load_data.column_names[column])
                continue
            if column == "E" or column == "G" or column == "I" or column == "J":
                requested_information += "The " + load_data.column_names[column] + " is " + phone_formatter(main_cell) + ".\n"
            elif column == "M" or column == "N" or column == "O" or column == "P":
                requested_information += "The " + load_data.column_names[column] + " is " + "${:,.2f}".format(float(main_cell)) + ".\n"
            elif column == "Q":
                requested_information += "The " + load_data.column_names[column] + " is " + "{:.2%}".format(float(str(main_cell))) + ".\n"
            elif column == "D" or column == "F" or column == "H":
                if main_cell != None or main_cell == "":
                    if rasa_actions_settings.include_email_functions == False:
                        requested_information += ("The " + load_data.column_names[column] + " is " + main_cell + ".\n")
                    #else:
                        ##NOTE - Uncomment procedures to enable personal emails being attached to the employees' contact info
                        #email = email_functions.GetEmailAddress(main_cell)
                        #firstName = main_cell.split(" ")
                        #requested_information += ("The " + load_data.column_names[column] + " is " + main_cell + " and " + firstName[0] + "'s email address is " + email + ".\n")
            elif column == "R":
                date = main_cell.split(" ")[0]
                requested_information += "The " + load_data.column_names[column] + " is " + "{}/{}/{}".format(date[5:7], date[8:], date[0:4]) + ".\n"
            else:
                requested_information += "The " + load_data.column_names[column] + " is " + main_cell + ".\n" 
        project_id_provided = True
    if len(missing_info_list) > 0:
        missing_info += " There doesn't seem to be any information for the following catagories: \n"
        first_item_used = False
        for missing_catagory in missing_info_list:
            if first_item_used == False:
                first_item_used = True
                missing_info += missing_catagory
            else:
                missing_info += ", " + missing_catagory
        if len(missing_info_list) == 1:
            missing_info = " There doesn't seem to be any information for the " + missing_info_list[0]
        requested_information += "\n" + missing_info + "." #NOTE - HERE, THE STRINGS ARE COMBINED
    dispatcher.utter_message(requested_information)
```

Comment: What exact output channel are you using with Rasa?  If it's something HTML-ish for example, a newline character has no particular meaning, and you might need to use some tag such as `<br>` to actually get a line break.

Comment: Oh, you're probably right. I will test it real quick.

Comment: That was exactly what the problem was. Thank you so much! If you add that as an answer I will comment on it as the answer. I can't upvote yet since my rep is still too low. @jasonharper

Comment: Oh, sorry. You probably need more context on what it was haha. So Rasa X is HTML, so I just had to add the html break instead.